# Use variable in Sweave code chunk

Tags: r, sweave, literate-programming

I am trying to write a vignette based on some example data included with my package. I want the vignette to be as robust as possible to minor changes in example dataset -- for example an id changing.

What I was hoping to do is to define the ids in a hidden code chunk:

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
ex_id <- functionToGetID() ## Let's assume it returns 1.
@
```

Then use that variable to insert into functions later in the document. Something like:

```
<<>>=
someFunction(id = get("ex_id"))
@
```

The goal is for the text in the vignette to show:

```
someFunction(id = 1)  ## and NOT someFunction(id = get("ex_id"))
```

I am not sure how to inject a variable into the code chunk, such that the LaTeX result only shows the value of the variable, and not how the variable was called.